# Material-web-component onChange not working

Tags: reactjs, material3

I am trying to make a signup form and want to get the live values in react with useState using material3 web. But onChange is not working with the component. How can I achieve this?

This is the code I am using.

```
import { React, useState } from "react";
import "@material/web/textfield/outlined-text-field.js";

const Otp = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { target } = event;
    const { name, value } = target;
    if (name === "name") setName(value);
    else if (name === "email") setEmail(value);
    console.log("handling change");
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Submit your form data here
    alert(`Name: ${name}, Email: ${email}`);
  };
  return (
    <md-outlined-text-field
      style={{ margin: "0 1rem" }}
      label="Phone Number"
      type="tel"
      onChange={handleChange}
    ></md-outlined-text-field>
  );
};

export default Otp;
```

I tried the code given above. The onChange function is not being called.

Answer (score 0):

In the source [code](https://github.com/material-components/material-web/blob/main/textfield/internal/text-field.ts) the text field component fires a 'input' (among others like change and select) event, more on that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/input_event). Which is equivalent to OnInput in react.

So you can use it this way:

```
<md-outlined-text-field
  style={{ margin: "0 1rem" }}
  label="Phone Number"
  type="tel"
  onInput={event => {handleChange(event)}}
></md-outlined-text-field>
```